# Vue2: Unable to bind a prop to a named slot

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I'm not sure why this isn't working... should be straight forward. I'm unable to bind a simple object to a named slot in one of my components:

I should be able to do the following:

1. Create a named slot and then bind a property to it:

```
<slot name="actions" :item="item" />


data(){
 return {
   item: {val1: 1, val2: 2}
 }
}
```

1. Use it in this fashion:

```
<template #actions="{ item }">

  <pre>{{ item }}</pre>

</template>
```

However, when I do this, this slot will not even render...

Below is my entire component code:

```
<template>
    <v-dialog v-model="dialog" :persistent="persistent" :width="width">
        <template #activator="{ on: dialogActivator, attrs: dialogAttrs }">
            <v-tooltip bottom :disabled="!tooltipText">
                <template #activator="{ on: tooltipActivator, tooltipAttrs }">
                    <v-btn
                        v-bind="{ ...dialogAttrs, ...tooltipAttrs, ...$attrs }"
                        v-on="{ ...dialogActivator, ...tooltipActivator }"
                        @click="$emit('handle-dialog-open-click')"
                    >
                        <slot name="activator"> Open </slot>
                    </v-btn>
                </template>
                <span>{{ tooltipText }}</span>
            </v-tooltip>
        </template>

        <v-card :height="cardHeight">
            <v-card-title
                v-if="hasTitleSlot"
                class="d-flex justify-space-between"
            >
                <slot name="title" />
            </v-card-title>
            <slot v-if="dialog" />
            <v-card-actions v-if="hasActionsSlot" class="d-flex justify-end">
                <slot name="actions" :item="obj" />
            </v-card-actions>
        </v-card>
    </v-dialog>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    inheritAttrs: false,
    props: {
        width: {
            type: String,
            default: '500',
        },
        tooltipText: {
            type: String,
            default: '',
        },
        persistent: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false,
        },
        cardHeight: {
            type: String,
            default: '',
        },
    },
    data() {
        return {
            dialog: false,
            obj: {
                val1: 1,
                val2: 2,
            },
        };
    },
    computed: {
        hasTitleSlot() {
            return !!this.$slots.title;
        },
        hasActionsSlot() {
            return !!this.$slots.actions;
        },
    },
    created() {
        this.$root.$on('close-dialog', this.closeModal);
    },
    beforeDestroy() {
        this.$root.$off('close-dialog', this.closeModal);
    },
    methods: {
        closeModal() {
            this.dialog = false;
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

It feels like its a simple typo somewhere...

EDIT:
Confirming that it works fine if I do not try to extract the prop like this:

```
<template #actions>
  Some awesome action goes here
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is is in `v-if="hasActionsSlot"`

```js
hasActionsSlot() {
  return !!this.$slots.actions;
},
```

This method always returns false as your `<slot name="actions" :item="obj" />` is not a regular slot, it is a scoped slot! And because this is not Vue 3 (where all slots, scoped or not are part of `$slots`), you need to use:

```js
hasActionsSlot() {
  return !!this.$scopedSlots.actions;
},
```

See [$slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-slots) VS [$scopedSlots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-scopedSlots)

> since 2.6.0+: All `$slots` are now also exposed on `$scopedSlots` as functions. If you work with render functions, it is now recommended to always access slots via `$scopedSlots`, whether they currently use a scope or not. This will not only make future refactors to add a scope simpler, but also ease your eventual migration to Vue 3, where all slots will be functions.

So in Vue 2.6+ it is always safer to work with `$scopedSlots` (as it contains all the slots)

Comment: That makes sense on why this method worked on my Vue3 app and why I was having a problem in Vue2